# Call procedure on Oracle 11.2.0 via JayDeBeApi in Python

Tags: python, sql, oracle, ojdbc, jaydebeapi

I am trying to call `dbms_random.seed(42)` on my DB, see [ref](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_random.htm#i996798). I need to use python and the `JayDeBeApi` connector. So far I've only been able to execute `select` statement without issue. I fail to understand what I am doing wrong.

It seems that `JayDeBeApi` does not provide the [callproc](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#callproc) method, so I cannot use it:

```
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'callproc'
```

I've naively tried:

```
conn = jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver',
    ['jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521/dbname', 'user', 'password'])
curs = conn.cursor()
sql="exec dbms_random.seed(42)"
curs.execute(sql)
```

but this leads to: `Error: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

I've tried two solutions which seems to have correct syntax, but since the generator is not deterministic, I believe they actually failed:

Using `begin/end`:

```
sql="begin dbms_random.seed(42); end;"
curs.execute(sql)
```

Using `call`:

```
sql="{ call dbms_random.seed(42) }"
curs.execute(sql)
```

So my question is: how do I call `dbms_random.seed(42)` on `Oracle` using `JayDeBeApi` ? As a side question how do I check that a statement has actually failed to execute (no exception was thrown and return value for [execute](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) is undefined.)

Update:

In fact the seed initialization is working as expected, since the results are what I expect for:

```
sql="SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.value FROM dual"
curs.execute(sql)
data = curs.fetchall()
print(data)
```

However I still see some odd behavior for my random query selection:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
    SELECT *
    FROM   table
    ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM)
WHERE  rownum < 21;
```

For some reason in the latter case, the `DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM` is actually random...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After multiple trial and error, I believe this is just a side effect. Since I was not doing the cleanup pass:

```
curs.close()
conn.close()
jpype.shutdownJVM()
```

The query would lead to somewhat undefined behavior. Now that I have a proper cleanup code, I am getting deterministic results when calling multiples times my python script.